# Does Localytics have a maven/gradle repository?

Tags: android, localytics

For the Android platform, the official guide doesn't mention a maven or gradle respository, but since it could be that it is just not documented I decided to search for it. I found four repos for the query string "localytics" but can't tell for sure if they're official:

[image]

Is any of those the official repo? does it even have one? (I'm avoiding including the `*.jar` directly)

Answer (score 2):

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven { url 'http://maven.localytics.com/public' }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.1.0'
    compile 'com.localytics.android:library:3.5+'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Localytics have package name `com.localytics.android` and all suggestions from search does not have any similar package. So, Localytics does not have any maven/gradle repository.

My point of view: These are not official Localytics libraries. They are missing few classes. The library I am using, has size of ~300kb.